# How to get all videos from a youtube channel

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, beautifulsoup

I am getting only 30 results but the channel has around 600 videos can anyone please help in getting all the videos. The below is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVlMUh4WsDQvOxCJJXmWwdw/videos"
uClient=urlopen(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
containers=page.findAll("div",{"class":"yt-lockup-dismissable"})
vids = page.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'})
print(len(vids))`
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have to find the URL attached to the "Show More" button and send a GET request to that. You have to keep doing so until the "Show More" button isn't there.

Comment: You may not know that the easiest way of downloading a channel of videos from youtube involves using https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/. You can also run it from Python.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly but you need to give the playlist link not the channel link. @Pavan